# Can Ionic apps send content to a second screen/projector?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I have done some research on Cordova/Phonegap, and it seems to me that Ionic is a great UI framework for writing hybrid apps with Cordova.

I want to make an app that can send a different screen to an external screen, like a projector connected via Google Chromecast or similar.

It seems I could use this plugin https://github.com/fraunhoferfokus/cordova-plugin-presentation with Cordova.

My question is: Is there any way I can use this or similar plugins with Ionic (Ionic Native plugin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use this plugin with Ionic2.

You're not forced to use Ionic Native plugin.

All "classical" Cordova plugins work with Ionic2 (like you can do standard JavaScript with Typescript).